# How to ajax a css progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

The content loads first before the ajax has been call, my goal is to have the progress bar load, then fetch the sites content, and i want to achieve this effect for each page load, something similar to a site like

https://medium.com/

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>YouTube Load AJAX TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptate mollitia eum, sunt rem. Laboriosam libero molestias architecto at, vitae culpa, doloribus commodi earum excepturi quidem repellendus rem eius eaque laudantium fuga facere laborum aliquam. Incidunt sit quam nulla similique dicta expedita quaerat perferendis exercitationem! Quis excepturi culpa pariatur sit libero, fugiat qui est, blanditiis, quod ut perferendis aliquam! Accusantium vitae eum saepe. Minima itaque asperiores fugit fugiat animi, incidunt veritatis nostrum. Velit cumque, officia temporibus perferendis minima ut! Ducimus labore, cupiditate libero nostrum ipsa a aut fuga, cumque molestiae dolorem omnis quam ex dolorum fugiat iste velit! Repellat quos provident, soluta!
</p>


<!-- GET JAVASCRIPT FILES -->

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

THE CSS

```
#loadingbar {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2147483647;
top: 0;
left: -6px;
width: 1%;
height: 4px;
background: #4EED66;

-moz-border-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}



#loadingbar.waiting dd, #loadingbar.waiting dt {
-moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
-ms-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
-o-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
-webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
}


@keyframes pulse {
30% { opacity:0.6; }
60% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0.6; }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
30% { opacity:0.6; }
60% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0.6; }
}

@-ms-keyframes pulse {
30% { opacity:0.6; }
60% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0.6; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
30% { opacity:0.6; }
60% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:0.6; }
}
```

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function() {
if ($("#loadingbar").length === 0) {
    $("body").append("<div id='loadingbar'></div>")
    $("#loadingbar").addClass("waiting").append($("<dt/><dd/>"));
    $("#loadingbar").width((50 + Math.random() * 30) + "%");
}
},
complete : function() {
$("#loadingbar").width("101%").delay(200).fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
}
});


$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url:"http://localhost/youtube%20load/"
}).done(function(data) {
console.log("one");
});




});
```

I would gladly appreciate the help.

Comment: what is your specific question? WHat works or doesn't work in your code?

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if you find answer to that question already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+ajax+a+css+progress+bar

Comment: @charlietfl the ajax isnt working, im trying to get the progress bar to load "first" then show the content.

I'm trying to achieve the youtube progress load effect.